# Retrieving date data from select query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm selecting from a database and echoing the results in a table. Everything worked ok until I change one column datatype from `varchar` to `date`. My first query (when column Date_PP datatype was `varchar`) was:

```
$queryitem = "SELECT Date_PP, Com, Doc, Place, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8 
              FROM MyTable 
              WHERE Com>=12 
              ORDER BY Date_PP ";
```

That worked ok, but `Date_PP` was a string, not real date data. After changing the db column from `varchar` to `date`, I modified the query to:

```
$queryitem = "SELECT Date_PP, Com, Doc, Place, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, 
              DATE_FORMAT(Date_PP, '%Y-%m-%d') AS Date_PP 
              FROM MyTable 
              WHERE Com>=12
              ORDER BY Date_PP ";
```

The complete piece of code is:

```
$queryitem = "SELECT Date_PP, Com, Doc, Place, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, 
              DATE_FORMAT(Date_PP, '%Y-%m-%d') AS Date_PP
              FROM MyTable
              WHERE Com>=12
              ORDER BY Date_PP ";
if ($result = $link->query($queryitem))  {
    if ($success = $result->num_rows > 0) {
        $ac=0;
        while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td > ".$row[1]." ".$row[2]."</td>";
            echo "<td > ".$row[3]."</td>";
            if ($row[0]=="" or isnull($row[0])) {
                echo "<td > not yet </td>";
            }
            else {
                echo "<td> ".$row[0]." </td>";
            }
            for ($i = 4; $i <= 11; $i++) {
                echo "<td >".$row[$i]."</td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
}
```

But now I can't echo the results. Code stops when echoing `$row[0]`.My guess is that date data is no longer "placed" in `$row[0]`, but can't get this to work. Anyone can spot the problem?

Comment: You have to change date string value in date format by using STR_TO_DATE function in mysql.

Answer (score 1):

You changed the column's type. If the column's contents weren't compatible with the new type, then it is removed, perhaps made `null` or some other appropriate "zero-value". You've nuked your data. Hope you had a backup!

For the record, `date` columns behave like string values in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`. You give it that, it stores it in an internal format, and returns that format back. You don't need to do anything there.

Comment: The table is a new and small one (20 rows). All values are right now `null` except only one value, that reads `2016-02-02`

Comment: There was no problem handing the data, but a typo in the code: in the echoing part, `is_null` is incorrectly stated as `isnull`. Still do not undestand why if all date values in db where `NULL` the code run ok, but when there was a actual date it stops working.

Is there a way to delete this post? The problem was not the one that the title states.